# What is the practice for handling Vuex action outcomes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating a login system using Vue and Vuex following this guide

https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex#toc-setup-components

This have the login action return a promise, which I was told does not follow the Flux Pattern which Vuex is based on.

So I've changed it up a bit and done the following:

```
// This is the action from my "auth store"
login: ({commit}, userData) => {
  commit('auth_request')
  Api.post('login', userData)
  .then(res => { 
    const token = res.data.data.token
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    Api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
    commit('auth_success', token)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    commit('auth_error')
    console.log("Failed to login, check your username or password")
  })    
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, but when I press my login button in my application I see all the commits come through, **auth_request**, **auth_success** and the store gets filled with user data from that **auth_success**.

But since I now does not return a promise, how can I now ask the router to change the view? I have no "feedback" on when the system is done loading? What is the best practice for acknowledging a successful or failed login?

Comment: I probably could add a "setInterval" which checked every 10 second for a change, but that would be a bit weird right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that it's an anti-pattern to return from a Promise is something that was a React driven ideology to push the idea of Flux. The piece of the puzzle that you would be missing is the `dispatcher` to listen to when an `action` finally calls it.

You would listen to it like an `event listener`, something like`:

```
this.$flux.on('login', (data) => {
  //login was called here
})
```

And you would dispatch it something like:

```
this.$flux.emit('login', data)
```

The idea is that you're not wholly reliant on a single piece of architecture which may in fact have side-effects, or, alternatively, may actually represent changes *all over your system*.

The down side to this is that you're adding another layer of data management to your application. You can completely forego this in smaller app's and just use `async/await` with `try/cache` and return a `Promise.resolve/reject`. However, maybe you want to learn the Flux pattern. It's super simple in Vue.

Make a new File called `bus.js`. Inside of this file, we'll actually just create a new Vue instance and export it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const Bus = new Vue({})

export default Bus
```

Now we can go ahead and import that, say in our login page:

```
import Bus from 'bus'
```

And in our `mounted` function, we can add a listener:

```
Bus.$on('login.success', this.loginHappened)
```

And in our `methods` in that `Login` component, we can define `loginHappened`.

```
loginHappened (data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Now we just dispatch it from our Action:

```
// store

import Bus from 'bus'

login: async ({ commit }, userData) => {
  try {
    const res = await Api.post('login', userData)

    const token = res.data.data.token
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    Api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
    commit('auth_success', token)

    Bus.$emit('login.sucesss', res.data.data)
  } catch (err) {
    Bus.$emit('login.failure', err.response.data)
  }
}
```

Oh, you'll also want to watch that failure:

```
Bus.$on('login.failure', this.loginFailed)
```

And now in that same Login component, or anywhere really, you can define that method:

```
loginFailed (error) {
  console.log(error) // the server side data from axios.
}
```

Now we have a system where actions are completely asynchronous and decoupled, and we rely on event dispatching and listeners in order to react to asynchronous actions.

Of course all of this is completely overkill for a 3 page SPA.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a bunch :) going for promises with a better conscious now! As this is a minor app and other pages don't need this information :)